# Ensure values are not the same in a column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I have a table with a column where the values should not be the same. Due to poor implementation software does not check to ensure if user enters a duplicate or not, therefore I was entrusted with a task of writing a "simple" sql statement or function that would look at all the values in the column and ensure they are not identical. The sql itself will be executed once a month so it does not have to be efficient.

The column stores int and I would like to increment one of the duplicate values, and keep on doing it every time until there are no more entries in the table that have the same value for the column. Any suggestion what I should do? I am not sure where to even start.

Thanks to anyone for their insight.

EDIT: Sorry forgot to mention that the values in the data that are not duplicate should stay that way. These are the settings used for customers, and we should punish them only if they have duplicate values. If they do not, then we should not destroy their settings or they will be angry.

It is just one table, contains a lot of columns, but this one specific column in particular which is of type int and never contains any nulls, should not have any duplicates.

Comment: What is that column used for?

Comment: @Quillion, how many number of columns you have to check, please elaborate the table structure as well.

Comment: Is this column referenced by any other table or data? It sounds as though it should have originally been an auto_increment column, and that you are now trying to force the values to once again be unique. But if that is so, there is a possibility you're using it as a foreign key else where (though without the foreign key constraint).  Also, does it really matter what new value you give any of the duplicates?  Can't it just be any unused integer?

Comment: The column itself does not require to be auto incremented and is used to store customer settings. The problem is that it should not store duplicate values and my company decided that implementing an sql to be run once a month to fix erros will be cheaper than fixing the software.

Comment: @Quillion - `Also, does it really matter what new value you give any of the duplicates? Can't it just be any unused integer?` Plus, a new question. If two records have the same value, and you don't want to 'punish' the person who chose that value first, can you see who chose that value first, and if so, how?

Comment: @Dems The table belongs to one customer only, and each customer has their own database. So if it is a duplicate it is made by same customer. So duplicates should be punished, and yes I would like to use any unused integer if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 create table tableName (KeyCol int identity(1,1), intCol int)
 insert into tableName values (1), (2), (2), (3), (5), (6), (5), (7), (9)


While exists (
    select intCol
    from tableName
    group by intCol
    having count(*) > 1
)
begin

    declare @newValue int

    select @newValue = min(t1.intCol) + 1
    from tableName t1
    left join tableName t2
    on t1.intCol + 1 = t2.intCol
    where t2.intCol is null

    update tx
    set intCol = @newValue
    from tableName tx
    where intCol = 
    (select top 1 intCol
    from tableName t1
    group by intCol
    having count(*) > 1
    order by intCol)
    and KeyCol = (select min(KeyCol) from tableName t2 where t2.intCol = tx.intCol)
end

select * from tableName order by 2
```

Comment: Ok, my code was full of bugs! Here's a working version for SQL2008: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/19801/2

Answer (score 1):

To get an idea of the size of the problem try something like the following, it's Oracle syntax as I don't know mysql but there should be an equivalent.

```
SELECT your_col, COUNT(your_col)
  FROM your_table
 GROUP BY your_col
```

I really don't think incrementing a value when you find a duplicate is the way to go, you may well create another duplicate while resolving the first, effectively after each increment you'd have to check again from the start. Correct approach is to add validation to whatever is used to enter the data to reject any duplicates. Then at least you only have to clean your data once.

Sorry if that's not what you were hoping for :-)

ETA Your company is wrong, running an sql once a week won't be cheaper, at least in the long run. You're slapping a plaster on something that needs stitches. Far better to take the hit now and solve the underlying problem, for a start, a column that doesn't want any duplicates, yet allows them to be entered anyway? There's a majot WTF to start with.

Answer (score 0):

why not to drop this column and recreate or repopulate it again with unique data and put on it UNIQUE INDEX?

Comment: If it is allowable to re-number any of these values, I'd assume it's allowable to re-number them all. In which case that may be a good quick-win option. Except that the OP is implying the cause of the problem won't be fixed, and so this will re-run every month, getting slower and slower. Arg!  ***[OP just posted an edit to say that this is not an option...]***

Comment: If those values are not very important (since they may be changed), it may be used auto-incerementing column.